# if the class is active, reinstate the other with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update the comments of a post. Let's say the user has 2 comments, when he clicks edit I want to close the window of the other comment. In short, how can I keep one as "textarea" and the other as "span"?

```js
$(document).on('click','.update-comment',function(e){
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
     let obj = $(this).closest('.comments');
   let text = obj.find('.comment-text').attr('data-text');  
   obj.find('.ms-3').addClass('active');
     if($('.ms-3').hasClass('active')){
      $(obj.find('.comment-text')).replaceWith('<textarea id="updateComment">'+text+'</textarea>');
   }else {
      $(obj.find('.comment-text')).replaceWith('<span class="comment-text" data-text='+text+'>'+text+'</span>');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex py-2 comments" data-id="1">
 <div class="flex-shrink-0">
  <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="..."/>
 </div>
  <div class="ms-3">
    <div class="fw-bold">Name-1
     <button type="submit" class="update-comment" data-id="1">Edit</button>
  </div>
    <span class="comment-text" data-text="Comment Example - 1" data-id="1">Comment Example - 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="d-flex py-2 comments" data-id="2">
 <div class="flex-shrink-0">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="..."/>
 </div>
  <div class="ms-3">
    <div class="fw-bold">Name-2
    <button type="submit" class="update-comment" data-id="2">Edit</button>
  </div>
    <span class="comment-text" data-text="Comment Example - 2" data-id="2">Comment Example - 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not trivial

I changed the button to type=button
I then removed the duplicate IDs and instead gave both span and textarea the class of comment-text

Then I changed the data-attr to just the .text() OR .val() depending on the element being a textarea or a span

I also cached several objects

```js
$(document).on('click', '.update-comment', function(e) {
  $allMS3 = $('.ms-3').removeClass('active');
  let $thisMS3 = $(this).closest('.ms-3')
    .addClass('active');
  $allMS3.each(function() {
    const $commentText = $(this).find('.comment-text')
    let text = $commentText.is("span") ? $commentText.text() : $commentText.val();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $commentText.replaceWith('<textarea class="comment-text">' + text + '</textarea>');
    } else {
      $commentText.replaceWith('<span class="comment-text">' + text + '</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex py-2 comments" data-id="1">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="ms-3">
    <div class="fw-bold">Name-1
      <button type="button" class="update-comment" data-id="1">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <span class="comment-text" data-text="Comment Example - 1" data-id="1">Comment Example - 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="d-flex py-2 comments" data-id="2">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="ms-3">
    <div class="fw-bold">Name-2
      <button type="button" class="update-comment" data-id="2">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <span class="comment-text" data-text="Comment Example - 2" data-id="2">Comment Example - 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```